# The difference between "had better not/hadn't better" in questions?

Tags: questions, modality

Is there a difference between these two:

> 1 Hadn't you better marry him?
>
> 2 Had you better not marry him?

It seems to me that 1 means "I recommend marrying him" and 2 means "I advise against marrying him".

Do you see this difference or am I seeing it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: It's the same as, for example, *Aren't you John Smith?* and *Are you not John Smith?*, or *Isn't he coming?* and *Is he not coming?* The non-contracted versions will often (but not *always*) seem a bit stilted / dated in normal conversational contexts.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Somehow I don't feel that the difference  in your examples is as clear-cut as in mine. It's only my feeling of course.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Offhand I can't think of any other versions of this particular "negation + possible contraction" ambiguity apart from this *to have better not* one, but maybe someone else can think of more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most purposes, OP's cited examples are the same as, for example,...

> *Aren't you John Smith?*
> *Are you not John Smith?*<sup>1</sup>
> or
> *Isn't he coming?*
> *Is he not coming?*

The non-contracted versions will often (but not *always*) seem a bit stilted / dated in normal conversational contexts, but normally that's the only difference. BUT in the *specific* case of negated non-contracted *to have better [do something]*, there's potential scope for ambiguity that doesn't usually apply to this construction.

***Had you better not go**?* is "naturally" interpreted the same as ***Hadn't you better go**?* (speaker suggesting to addressee that he ***should*** go). But *some* people would understand ***It would be better if you didn't go*** (esp. depending on the spoken stress pattern as noted below).

---

<sup>1</sup> In a real-world *spoken* context, if speaker was asking for confirmation that the person he was talking to ***wasn't*** John Smith, he'd put heavy stress on the word ***not*** (making it obviously the total opposite of the contracted version, where ***not*** has been so far reduced it doesn't even contain a vowel to carry that stress! :)